# How to design a winform be like webpage without using thirdparty control?

Tags: winforms, web-to-winforms

I have a winform and I want to design it like a webform I'm just wondering on how to do that matter in winform and I think it's possible because some third party controls have same exact design for the form. I just want to make my own control though. Here's an image like so.

[image]

Comment: Whan you say "Design it like a webform" what do you mean? It currently is very unclear what you are trying to point out in your picture and your question does not really explain what you are trying to replicate.

Comment: I want my winforms to be designed like the image shown.

Comment: And what is keeping you from writing the [custom controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx) to do so? (BTW, switching to WPF from winforms would make something like what you are showing a lot easyier to do)

Comment: And so I need to write it in a `XAML`?

Comment: You don't have to, it is just XAML (and more importantly the tools to write XMAL like Expression Blend) are easier to do layouts like you are showing.

Comment: This is a site for helping people through spcific problems they are having. If you want a tutorial or have someone write something for you this is the wrong site.

Comment: Just want to have some idea though. Thanks BTW

Comment: conceptually, that's just a `TabControl`, but winforms doesn't support any level of customization and making a winforms TabControl look like that requires and endless stream of hellish torture and pain, and a lot of horrible hacks. Use current, relevant technology (XAML) instead of winforms, and you can achieve this in some 15 minutes by writing a simple `ControlTemplate` for a `TabControl`.

Comment: @HighCore Can you give a idea on how to get started to that? I'm new to this `XAML` thing. Dunno how to manage `Blend` to this one

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18539966/643085) for a simple example. Further customization requires creating a new [`Template`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683(v=vs.110).aspx)for the TabControl. Forget winforms, it's useless.

Comment: @HighCore So how can I use it in winforms?